# Kotiln - toDouble 3 / Int 2 = 1.5?

Tags: java, kotlin, math

I study Kotlin now, in my book said

```
val num: Int = 15 - 4 * 3 
val num2: Int = 65 % 7
val num4: Double = num.toDouble() / num2 + 0.7

println(num4)
```

is 1.7

but my computer said '2.2'

```
println(num) // 3
println(num2)  //2
println(num.toDouble())  // 3.0
println(num.toDouble() / num2.toDouble())  // 1.5
println(num4)  // so 2.2
```

Which is the right one?

Comment: 2.2. It must be a misprint or there is something you are not showing us.

Comment: The only reasonable definition of "the right one" is what running the code actually gets.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Another reasonable definition could be "what the spec says", but I get what you mean.

Comment: Obviously ... the computer is right.  Programmer lesson #1 - the computer is right.  The bug is not in the compiler.  Except in very obscure circumstances ...

Comment: @NOH Please provide the title, author/publisher, and publishing date of the book, as well as the page number. I'd like to see if there are corrections published online.

Answer (score 1):

2.2 is what I get as well. If it was 66 instead of 65 then the result would be 1.7 so I'm assuming a misprint as well.